# How do I notify queue.join() in python to stop blocking even if the current queue contains unprocessed elements?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, priority-queue, blocking

I have main thread which block waits for the items in the priority queue (PQ) to processed by the consumer thread. The consumer thread receives items from a different populator thread. Whenever the consumer thread receives a high priority 'TERMINATOR' item, it dies. But since the main thread is waiting on the queue elements to be processed it never exits. Is there a way for me to notify the PQ.join() to return without using a while loop to empty my queue(large number of items in the queue is causing a lot of delay if I use a while loop)

Answer (score 2):

You could wait for the consumer thread instead of the priority queue, it seems like that is the thing you want to wait on, i.e. `consumer_thread.join()` instead of `PQ.join()`.

Comment: Yes, thanks this solved my problem. 

On an other note though, I don't understand why my PQ.join() doesn't unblock even though I make PQ.unfinished_tasks = 0 when the terminator object is encountered.

Comment: From the docs: ```Queue.task_done()
Indicate that a formerly enqueued task is complete. Used by queue consumer threads. For each get() used to fetch a task, a subsequent call to task_done() tells the queue that the processing on the task is complete.

If a join() is currently blocking, it will resume when all items have been processed (meaning that a task_done() call was received for every item that had been put() into the queue).

Raises a ValueError if called more times than there were items placed in the queue.``` link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Comment: This means that setting `PQ.unfinished_tasks = 0` doesn't trigger a  `join()` to continue, only calling `task_done()` as many times as you put items in does.